# Creating a HTTP proxy to handle mTLS connections with Hyper

Tags: rust, proxy, hyper

I need some help to create a proxy in hyper that resolves a mTLS connection. I used this example https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/0.14.x/examples/http_proxy.rs as a starting point, and worked through adding tokio-rustls to support the mTLS connection. Here is the code that handles the http tunnel.

```rust
async fn tunnel(
    mut upgraded: Upgraded,
    destination: (String, u16),
    certificates: Certificates,
) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let root_cert_store = prepare_cert_store(&certificates);
    let tls_client_config = tls_config(certificates, root_cert_store);
    let tls_connector = TlsConnector::from(Arc::new(tls_client_config));

    let target = TcpStream::connect(target_address(&destination)).await?;

    let domain = rustls::ServerName::try_from(destination.0.as_str()).expect("Invalid DNSName");

    let mut tls_target = tls_connector.connect(domain, target).await?;
    debug!("TlS Connection ready");
    let (wrote, recvd) = tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(&mut upgraded, &mut tls_target).await?;
    debug!("Client wrote {} and received {} bytes", wrote, recvd);
    Ok(())
}
```

To make the proxy connection I made a really small snippet in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val fm = FuelManager.instance
    fm.proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8100))

    repeat(1) {
        val response = "https://nginx-test".httpGet()
            .responseString()
        println("Response: $response")
        println("Response Data: ${response.second.data.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())}")
    }
}
```

It just sets the proxy address and makes a call to a local nginx server where the mTls auth is expected to occurs.

This kotlin code throws the following error `Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message`

And the Nginx logs the request like this:
`172.18.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2023:17:51:08 +0000] "\x16\x03\x03\x01\xBF\x01\x00\x01\xBB\x03\x03\xD90\xF6+\xCEIvRr\xEF\x84{\x82\xD0\xA0\xFB8\xAD\xEB\x11\x1D\xC4 " 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`

I'm assuming that the message is being delivered encrypted to the Nginx server and I can't really just copy the bytes from one connection to another like this  `let (wrote, recvd) = tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(&mut upgraded, &mut tls_target).await?;`

Maybe I should wrap the "upgraded" connection in some sort of TlsAcceptor so it can decrypt the bytes before writing it, but i could not figure out how to do it.

Anyone has any thoughts on this?

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen                  80;

    location / {
        return              301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             nginx.test;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    ssl_client_certificate  /etc/nginx/client_certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client       optional;
    ssl_verify_depth        2;

    location / {
        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) { return 403; }

        proxy_set_header     SSL_Client_Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn;
        proxy_set_header     SSL_Client $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header     SSL_Client_Verify $ssl_client_verify;

        return 200 "yay";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with rust but the nginx log shows that a plain HTTP site is access by HTTPS (`\x16\x03\x03...` is start of TLS handshake) - which results in an error 400.  So either nginx is not properly setup for HTTPS or you are using the wrong target port in your proxy. You seem to derive the target port from the `destination`  argument in fn tunnel, but it is not clear what the value of this argument is.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the insight, I edited the question to include the Nginx configuration, and the target port that I'm using is 443.

Comment: What is "upgraded"? If it has the same meaning as in the code you link to, the  you are not terminating TLS from client in your proxy but instead wrapping the original TLS traffic from the client in another TLS layer to nginx, i.e. TLS inside TLS where nginx expects only a single TLS layer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "upgraded" Its the established connection between the client and the Proxy after they made the initial HTTP "Connect" procedure to establish an http tunnel.
It makes sense what you said about TLS inside TLS, I'll look into it.

Comment: If you want to "transform" a plain TLS connection to an mTLS connection then you need to terminate the first one and create a new one with the decrypted traffic from the first. This TLS termination seems to be missing, i.e. `upgraded` must be the terminate TLS, not the original TCP from the client.